# Flash: making an arrow move

Tags: flash

How can i get the arrow to move all the time and make it die when it hits the walls, like in snake.  when my code is:

```
import flash.events.Event;

ting.stop();

var hastighed:Number = 50;
var flyt_vertikal:Number = 0;
var flyt_horizontal:Number = 0;

var point:Boolean = true;
var taeller:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeydown);

function onKeydown (e:KeyboardEvent):void

{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)

    {this.flyt_horizontal = hastighed;
        this.ting.gotoAndStop (1);

    }


    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)

    {this.flyt_horizontal = hastighed*-1;
        this.ting.gotoAndStop (2);

    }

    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)

    {this.flyt_vertikal = hastighed*-1;
        this.ting.gotoAndStop (3);

    }


    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
     this.flyt_vertikal = hastighed;
       this.ting.gotoAndStop (4);

    }

    }


stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyup);

function onKeyup(e:KeyboardEvent)

{


    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        flyt_horizontal = 0;
    }



    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {

        flyt_horizontal = 0;
    }



    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        flyt_vertikal = 0;
    }



    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        flyt_vertikal = 0;
    }
}




this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,animerObjekt);

function animerObjekt(evt:Event) {
   this.ting.x += flyt_horizontal;
      this.ting.y += flyt_vertikal;

      if(this.ting.x>stage.stageWidth - 10) {
         this.ting.x=stage.stageWidth -25;
         }

        if(this.ting.x< 25){
           this.ting.x =35;
           }

      if(this.ting.y > stage.stageHeight -25 ){
         this.ting.y = stage.stageHeight - 35;
         }

      if(this.ting.y< 25){
           this.ting.y =35;
           }

           if(this.ting.hitTestObject(this.maal) && point == true ){
               taeller++;
               point = false;
               }

            if(this.ting.hitTestObject(this.maal) == false) {

               point = true;
               }   



              if((this.ting.hitTestObject(this.maal2) && point == true )){
               taeller++;
               point = false;
               }

            if(this.ting.hitTestObject(this.maal2) == false) {

               point = true;
               }  

               this.point_tekst.text = String(taeller + "point");


}
```

Would be very glad if somebody could help me.

You can see a version of it on: http://grafisk.kts.dk/elever/chpe22/Jinn/snake_spil.html

Comment: Just check the coordinates everytime you move your arrow, if its x or y is higher or lower that the "Play screen" then kill the arrow.

Comment: Thats if you have the X and Y of the walls..

Comment: Where should i do that?

Comment: By the look of your code, it seems you are already doing it, except you are just pushing the arrow back, in the function "animerObjeckt".

Comment: If you want someone to help you, you should really try editing your question and explaining better what your problem is, and what you have already tried...